# Spark SQL Case statement

Tags: apache-spark-sql, case

I am getting a strange error from Spark SQL (on Azure Synapse and on Databricks) on case statement:

```
%%python
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, sequence, to_date

beginDate = '2023-01-01'
endDate = '2025-12-31'

(
  spark.sql(f"select explode(sequence(to_date('{beginDate}'), to_date('{endDate}'), interval 1 day)) as calendarDate")
    .createOrReplaceTempView('dates')
)

%%sql
select calendarDate
, month(calendarDate) monthNum
, case when month(calendarDate) = 1 and weekofyear(calendarDate) > 50 than 0 else weekofyear(calendarDate) end weekNum 
from dates
```

Error is:

```
Error: 
mismatched input 'month' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 4, pos 12)

== SQL ==
select calendarDate
, month(calendarDate) monthNum

, case when month(calendarDate) = 1 and weekofyear(calendarDate) > 50 than 0 else weekofyear(calendarDate) end weekNum 
------------^^^
```

I am getting results from month() in previous row.

Comment: `> 50 than 0 else` - is that supposed to be `THEN` ?

Comment: ah... thEn instead of thAn
Thx.